# Send email html body as Base64 encoded

Tags: mailkit, mimekit

How do I in Mimekit send an email having the html body base64 encoded?

In code I first create the entire body as a MimeEnitity including attachments using the BodyBuilder. Then I create the MimeMessage to be sent having the body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you'll need to do is to locate the HTML body part.

A quick hack might look something like this:

```
var htmlBody = message.BodyParts.OfType<TextPart> (x => x.IsHtml).FirstOrDefault ();
```

Then you'll need to set the Content-Transfer-Encoding:

```
htmlBody.ContentTransferEncoding = ContentEncoding.Base64;
```

That's it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had the body as a MimeEntity. The only part i was missing was casting it to a TextPart in order to set the ContentTransferEncoding.